# Crystal Report Show Multiple Records Following Parameter Fields

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report for a spa technicians schedule for their day. It consists of a scheduled time, and their break times.

I am making a crystal report and have the following set up in Preview:

[image: Preview mode look]

There is actually two breaks in my database, another one for `4:30 - 5:45`. How do I get this second one to show as well?

I have this set up in Design:

[image: Design mode look]

`@Breaks` has the formula `ToText(cTime({cmprovblk.from_time}),'h:mmtt') + '-' + ToText(cTime({cmprovblk.to_time}),'h:mmtt')`.

The desired result, crudely drawn, is:

[image: Desired preview mode look]

Here is the table that provides the schedule, filtered by `provider_code` and `sba_date`:

```
provider_code | property_code | sba_date   | from_time | to_time
--------------|---------------|------------|-----------|--------
100           |               | 2017-04-12 | 09:00     | 17:45
```

Here is the table that provides the breaks, filtered by `provider_code` and `sba_date`:

```
provider_code | sba_date   | from_time | to_time | block_reason_code
--------------|------------|-----------|---------|------------------
100           | 2017-04-12 | 12:45     | 13:30   | lunch
100           | 2017-04-12 | 16:30     | 17:45   | gonehome
```

Moving the breaks to the `Details a` section just makes it keep repeating for some reason.. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Breaks are repeating in Details a]

and this goes on for half the second page.

Here are my links:

[image: Links in my database]

Comment: Did you remove my answer or you created another case?

Answer (score 0):

You can put another `@Breaks` formula field just below the existing one and then `suppress` that with the condition like `if {Table1.from_time}="16:30" and {Table1.to_time}="17:45"  then  false Else true`. Similarly do the same for the previous `@Breaks` formula field too.

Comment: Breaks could be at any time throughout the day though, it would be near impossible to cover every single use case.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW you can apply the same logic for `block_reason_code` field